# When submitting a form I receive my error but not sure why

Tags: php, html

Why do I seem to receive my echo statement "error" when submitting this form?

I got this code from https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php for register.php.

It was working fine for my users up till yesterday and can't seem to find why?

I thought maybe it was my config.php but it does print the error message if a username is already in use so it doesn't seem to be config.php. I messaged the website that I got the code from and they couldn't help me.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM sign_in_account WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sign_in_account (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. error: 1";//Error 1 = form submission
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

The output should go to my login.php page on successful result submission but prints my echo statement "echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. error: 1";"

Comment: Something about your database connection is broken. `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` returns `false`. Have you changed anything about that?

Comment: which "error" statement??

Comment: Instead of saying "error: 1" why not actually check the error message?

Comment: @theblackips I haven't changed anything on my server in about 2 weeks. but it was working 2 days ago as we have had new users in my database created then. Then I was told that it wasn't working yesterday.

Comment: @CodyO'Meara As the others said, please check your php error log.

Comment: @theblackips how do I see a php log? When I say "error" im not talking about an actual error that's happening on my page with php. It is just an error that I send to the screen if something didn't execute like I wanted. All syntax is right on the added code its just that when doing 'if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))' with correct info it should redirect to the login.php and not display my echo statement. Its just weird that it randomly stopped working like my server updated or something to a new version and something with mysqli_stmt_execute isnt working the same.

Comment: There is a file where your webserver puts detailed information about all php errors. It's location depends on your operating system and webserver. You should be able to find it with the help of Google. I think for apache on linux you can find it at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Please edit your question to include the error details if you can find anything.